# Signal filtering with physical limitations and estimated STD

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, time-series, smoothing

I have a prediction mechanism that predicts some signal value. Generally the prediction look like this:

[image]

The are some ranges of systematic error and I cannot do anything with this. But in many points a post-processing filtering will obviously do a good job to bring predicted signal closer to truth signal.

I need to design a simple post-processing filter without look-ahead, also given that:

1. 1st derivative of Truth signal is known to have physical limits, say [-1;1]
2. prediction mechanism not only predicts value, but also estimates uncertainty as STD(prediction-truth) in each point. Where prediction is good and stable, uncertainty is low, where it is very noisy, uncertainty is high.

What type of filtering could you suggest if we only have (1) and if we have (1) and (2) in place?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! Interesting question. Can you clear up something for me: I’m confused about the difference between “look ahead” and “prediction”? I’m assuming the signal is the “prediction” and by “look ahead” you mean without using any future values of the prediction signal. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I assume it should be able to work in real time. We use some instant sensors data to obtain first prediction (and we cannot change this predictor), then we apply some filtering based on our knowledge about the physics of the process (we know that real truth value is pretty smooth).